# Is there a way to turn ON UAC programmatically with C#?

Tags: c#, windows-vista, uac

Is there a way to turn ON UAC programmatically with C#? I know, everyone seems to want to know how to turn it off. I want to be able to turn it on and restart the system.

Thanks

Comment: You should not be overriding a user's preference like this.  I for one would be really pissed if some app changed my preferred setting.

Comment: I agree, but I'll be doing it at their request.

Comment: Ahh, ok then.  I did a quick search and I could not find an API for this.

Comment: ...you probably did the same :)

Comment: I know how to do it on a Hyper-V VM from the host, if this is what you want I can type out the full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registry key seems to be at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA

Easiest way that I know how to restart is "shutdown -r -t 01"  You should be able to ShellExec it.